# Setting a max memory limit for process with ulimit

Tags: memory, ulimit

So I've learned that its hella easy to make a memory leak in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int* p;
    int i=0;
    
    p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    while (p!=NULL) {
        p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        i++;
    }
    printf("malloc failed after %d allocations\n",i);
}
```

And I wanted to see how I could avoid restarting my computer every time I launch this program (or just kill it before its too late).

`ulimit` seems to be the solution. `ulimit -S -m 1000000` should prevent any process to take more than 1000000 kbyte / 1gbyte of memory (I have a 32gbyte of RAM). But it seems to have absolutely no effect: when I launch the program above, it will use all of the memory if I don't kill it.

I tried setting a very low limit (100 kbyte...), or set a virtual memory limit (`-v`) instead of RSS but no effects were seen...

What did I miss?

Comment: `-S` sets a "soft" limit, which is advisory. Use `ulimit -H`  to set a hard (enforced) limit for your process.

Comment: Soft means it is ignored ? With the `-H` option I get `ulimit: max memory size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument`

Comment: "Soft" means that the limit can later be increased; "hard" that it can only be further reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ulimit -m` limits the *resident set size* of the process - i.e. how much of the process may be paged in at one time.

If you have swap available, the process's virtual memory can be much larger.

`ulimit -v` limits the amount of virtual memory that may be allocated, and that's what you want.  Note that it's not necessarily inherited by child processes, so use a subshell and `exec`:

```bash
( ulimit -v 1000000 && exec test_program )
```

Comment: This do work ! After 3 years I have my answer, thanks ! Note that (on mint 21), it do work without subshell (`ulimit -v 1000; ./test_program;`). But if I set `ulimit -v 100` alone, then I can't increase this value later on this shell (`operation not permitted`), which is weird.

Answer (score -2):

Ram (on most Unix systems) is lazily allocated on first write.  You don't write to the pointer you get back from malloc().

Comment: Well, I got the desired output ("malloc failed...") with Toby answer, so it's not that